# How do I plot a collection of csv files in gnuplot?

Tags: shell, unix, gnuplot

I have a collection of csv files with the same 2 column format. I'd like to produce separate xy scatter plots corresponding to each file, but with the same style. The only thing that should change is the input and output filenames. How to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution posted by andyras is perfectly workable.  However, in these instances, "HERE" files are typically better since it avoids spawning an extra process and since you won't have problems with mixing single quotes and double quotes ...

```
for file in $(echo *.dat); do
    gnuplot <<EOF
    set terminal post enh
    set output "output_${file}.ps"
    set datafile separator ','  #csv file
    plot "$file" u 1:2
EOF
done
```

Comment: I like this one because it is cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, create a text file containing all of the style information, say `gplot_prefix.txt`. Then, I assume you have some pattern that matches all of the files you want to plot, say `*.dat`. Then, make a zsh script as follows:

```
foreach arg in $@
    filename=${arg}_plotfile.pl
    cp gplot_prefix.txt ${filename}
    echo set output ${arg}.png >>${filename}
    echo plot \"${arg}\" u 1:2 >>${filename}
    gnuplot ${filename}
    rm ${filename}
```

(this may have bugs; my zsh isn't working correctly right now) and call it like

```
./plotscript.zsh *.dat
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a wrapper bash script and save it as `plot.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "set terminal postscript enhanced
set output 'output_$1.eps'

plot '$1'
```

Let's say your data files all have the `.dat` extension.  You would use this by calling

```
for datfile in $(ls *dat) ; do ./plot.sh $datfile ; done
```

at the command line in bash.

Comment: Oh, @Dan posted pretty much the same solution.